# Decompressing a byte array with zlib to a byte array

Tags: c++, sqlite, gzip, zlib, inflate

Context: I'm using a .mbtiles file, a geomapping file format, which is a sqlite database file containing vector tiles.

Those vector tiles are packed using protocol buffer and then gzipped.

I'm using C++, and currently reading the zlib usage decompression example, but I am not sure about how to handle chunks and the end of stream event.

SQLite gives me a void* pointer and a length.

I quote the page:

> For applications where zlib streams are embedded in other data, this
>   routine would need to be modified to return the unused data, or at
>   least indicate how much of the input data was not used, so the
>   application would know where to pick up after the zlib stream.

The protocol buffer class methods either take void* or std::string. I guess I should go with void*.

I'm not sure how those events work, and the example doesn't seem to provide a case for bytes arrays. How should I change the code to avoid errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like SQLite is giving you a zlib stream without anything after it. If so, then that comment doesn't apply.

In any case, you are looking at [the right page](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html). (You didn't say what "the page" is, but I recognize the quote, since I wrote it.) That shows in general how to use the zlib functions. You should be able to figure out how to apply it to a byte array instead of file input.

If the data is really "gzipped", then you will need to use `inflateInit2()` instead of `inflateInit()`. Read the [zlib documentation in zlib.h](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).